# fix Could not find android-support-v7-appcompat.apk

Tags: android, eclipse

I am using [android-support-v7-appcompat] for android project in eclipse. I am getting this error "android-support-v7-appcompat] Could not find android-support- v7-appcompat.apk!". please share your experience about this process

public class SmsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

```
private static String TAG = SmsActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private ViewPager viewPager;
private ViewPagerAdapter adapter;
private Button btnRequestSms, btnVerifyOtp;
private EditText inputName, inputEmail, inputMobile, inputOtp;
private ProgressBar progressBar;
private PrefManager pref;
private ImageButton btnEditMobile;
private TextView txtEditMobile;
private LinearLayout layoutEditMobile;

    // Checking for user session
    // if user is already logged in, take him to main activity
    if (pref.isLoggedIn()) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(SmsActivity.this, Home.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK            Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(intent);

        finish();
    }

    adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter();
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });


    /**
     * Checking if the device is waiting for sms
     * showing the user OTP screen
     */
    if (pref.isWaitingForSms()) {
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
        layoutEditMobile.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.btn_request_sms:
            validateForm();
            break;

        case R.id.btn_verify_otp:
            verifyOtp();
            break;

        case R.id.btn_edit_mobile:
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
            layoutEditMobile.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            pref.setIsWaitingForSms(false);
            break;
    }
}

/**
 * Validating user details form
 */
private void validateForm() {
    String name = inputName.getText().toString().trim();
    String email = inputEmail.getText().toString().trim();
    String mobile = inputMobile.getText().toString().trim();

    // validating empty name and email
    if (name.length() == 0 || email.length() == 0) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter your details", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }

    // validating mobile number
    // it should be of 10 digits length
    if (isValidPhoneNumber(mobile)) {

        // request for sms
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        // saving the mobile number in shared preferences
        pref.setMobileNumber(mobile);

        // requesting for sms
        requestForSMS(name, email, mobile);

    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter valid mobile number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

/**
 * Method initiates the SMS request on the server
 *
 * @param name   user name
 * @param email  user email address
 * @param mobile user valid mobile number
 */
private void requestForSMS(final String name, final String email, final String mobile) {

    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            Config.URL_REQUEST_SMS, new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d(TAG, response.toString());

            try {
                JSONObject responseObj = new JSONObject(response);

                // Parsing json object response
                // response will be a json object
                boolean error = responseObj.getBoolean("error");
                String message = responseObj.getString("message");

                // checking for error, if not error SMS is initiated
                // device should receive it shortly
                if (!error) {
                    // boolean flag saying device is waiting for sms
                    pref.setIsWaitingForSms(true);

                    // moving the screen to next pager item i.e otp screen
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
                    txtEditMobile.setText(pref.getMobileNumber());
                    layoutEditMobile.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "msg", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Error: " + message,
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                // hiding the progress bar
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Error: " + e.getMessage(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"msg1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  //  error. getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }) {

        /**
         * Passing user parameters to our server
         * @return
         */
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("name", name);
            params.put("email", email);
            params.put("mobile", mobile);

            Log.e(TAG, "Posting params: " + params.toString());

            return params;
        }

    };

    int socketTimeout = 60000;
    RetryPolicy policy = new DefaultRetryPolicy(socketTimeout,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);
    strReq.setRetryPolicy(policy);

    // Adding request to request queue
    MyApplication.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq);
}

/**
 * sending the OTP to server and activating the user
 */
private void verifyOtp() {
    String otp = inputOtp.getText().toString().trim();

    if (!otp.isEmpty()) {
        Intent grapprIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HttpService.class);
        grapprIntent.putExtra("otp", otp);
        startService(grapprIntent);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter the OTP", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

/**
 * Regex to validate the mobile number
 * mobile number should be of 10 digits length
 *
 * @param mobile
 * @return
 */
private static boolean isValidPhoneNumber(String mobile) {
    String regEx = "^[0-9]{10}$";
    return mobile.matches(regEx);
}


class ViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == ((View) object);
    }

    public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {

        int resId = 0;
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                resId = R.id.layout_sms;
                break;
            case 1:
                resId = R.id.layout_otp;
                break;
        }
        return findViewById(resId);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: which jdk version you use?its require jdk 8

Comment: am using jdk 1.7(i.e. 7 version)

Comment: update it to 1.8 and also update sdk

Comment: sdk is fully updated upto API 23, but we building app for the verion of API 14- API 19 ...

Comment: whats target version of appcompact??

Comment: target version of app-compact is 22

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87359/discussion-between-baskar-a-and-mahesh-suthar).

Answer (score 0):

Try:

1. Right Click on Package Explorer Import
2. Android > Existing Android Code into Workspace > Next
3. Browse > ~/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat
4. Select the package. Checkbox "Copy projects into workspace" > Finish
5. Right Click in YOUR PROJECT > Properties > Android
6. In the section of Library > Add > appcompat > OK
7. Finally go to Project (in the menu of eclipse) > Clean ..

Tell us if you tried something and what happened.

**NOTE**:***appcompat target version and your project target version should be same***